# We are using JMeter to test a Salesforce application.The login takes 35 secs from JMeter for single user,however from UI it takes maybe 15secs

Tags: jmeter, salesforce, load-testing, response-time

Showing this value to the client would raise questions. How to clarify the response time.
There are multiple requests in one transaction, the UI runs these requests in parallel and JMeter runs these sequentially and adds the response times of all sub-request .Could that be the reason for high response times only from JMeter.? IF so then JMeter has an issue and not reliable !?

Please help on this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If "UI runs these requests in parallel" then JMeter must run these requests in parallel as well.

If the requests are related to so called ["embedded resources"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) - images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc. - just tick the appropriate box in the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) and remove the individual calls to images, scripts, etc from your test plan

[image]

If the "requests" you're talking about are i.e. [AJAX calls](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) you can "tell" JMeter to run them in parallel by placing them under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) (it's a plugin installable via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T.

Comment: The request has multiple sub-requests Sample : Login has 1. /secur/contentDoor-65 2./visualforce/session-69 3./one/one.app-71 and 30 more. You mean we have give retrieve all embedded resources for each of these sub requests ? Also, these are separate sub-requests can they control all the subrequest?

Answer (score 0):

We were using loadrunner with a similar issue. However, we decided to continue to use loadrunner to apply the load, but the real response times were captured with Loadrunner's Truclient. This is a light weight browser. We run about 10 txns per hour to get the actual response times while applying the load with the regular web scripts.